# Entertaining examples of multiply quantified statements

Tags: logic

I am teaching a discrete math course, and doing multiply quantified statements. All the book examples are sober and forgettable:

> Every real number has a reciprocal.
>
> For all triangles x [in a "Tarski world" with a bunch of shapes of different colors], there is a square y such that x and y have the same color.
>
> There is no smallest positive real number.

And so on. These are good, but I would like to supplement these with examples from pop culture, song lyrics, contemporary politics, etc. -- especially anything amusing, complicated, and/or which drastically changes meaning when you change the order of the quantifiers. Something the students might remember the day after the lecture.

Usually I am good at this kind of thing but for now I am drawing a blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Zero does not have a reciprocal.

Answer (score 9):

For single quantifiers, there is the standard -- *jazz* standard -- [example](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/12/11/cannot-fool/):

- Everybody loves my baby.
- My baby loves nobody but me.

For multiple quantifiers, a [classic](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/12/11/cannot-fool/) is:

- You can fool all of the people some of the time
- You can fool some of the people all of the time
- But you can't fool all the people all the time.

Answer (score 4):

You could have students draw up the quantifications for the following, taken from *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*.

> ‘Then you should say what you mean,’ the March Hare went on.
>
> ‘I do,’ Alice hastily replied; ‘at least--at least I mean what I
>   say--that’s the same thing, you know.’
>
> ‘Not the same thing a bit!’ said the Hatter. ‘You might just as well
>   say that “I see what I eat” is the same thing as “I eat what I see”!’
>
> ‘You might just as well say,’ added the March Hare, ‘that “I like what
>   I get” is the same thing as “I get what I like”!’
>
> ‘You might just as well say,’ added the Dormouse, who seemed to be
>   talking in his sleep, ‘that “I breathe when I sleep” is the same thing
>   as “I sleep when I breathe”!’

Or the following, from *Through the Looking Glass*.

> ‘Who did you pass on the road?’ the King went on, holding out his hand
>   to the Messenger for some more hay.
>
> ‘Nobody,’ said the Messenger.
>
> ‘Quite right,’ said the King: ‘this young lady saw him too. So of
>   course Nobody walks slower than you.
>
> ‘I do my best,’ the Messenger said in a sulky tone. ‘I’m sure nobody
>   walks much faster than I do!’
>
> ‘He can’t do that,’ said the King, ‘or else he’d have been here first.
>   However, now you’ve got your breath, you may tell us what’s happened
>   in the town.’

Comment: I approve of using *Alice*! (Second one is from *Through the Looking Glass* though.)

Comment: Oops, you are right. I glanced too quickly at the heading. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

There's a lovely bit from *Catch-22* that I'm quite fond of (I'll boldface the relevant part, but you really need the full passage to appreciate how wonderfully Carollian it is):

> "All right," said the colonel. "Just what the hell did you mean?"
>
> "I didn't say  you couldn't punish me, sir."
>
> "When?" asked the colonel.
>
> "When what, sir?"
>
> "Now you're asking me questions again."
>
> "I'm sorry, sir. I'm afraid I don't understand your question."
>
> "When didn't you say we couldn't punish you? Don't you understand my question?"
>
> "No, sir. I don't understand."
>
> "You've just told us that. Now suppose you answer my question."
>
> "But how can I answer it?"
>
> "That's another question you're asking me."
>
> "I'm sorry, sir. But I don't know how to answer it. **I never said you couldn't punish me."**
>
> "Now you're telling us when you did say it. **I'm asking you to tell us when you didn't say it."**
>
> Clevinger took a deep breath. **"I always didn't say you couldn't punish me, sir."**
>
> "That's much better, Mr. Clevinger, even though it is a barefaced lie. Last night in the latrine. Didn't you whisper that we couldn't punish you to that other dirty son of a bitch we don't like? What's his name?"
>
> "Yossarian, sir," Lieutenant Scheisskopf said.
>
> "Yes, Yossarian. That's right. Yossarian. Yossarian? Is that his name? Yossarian? What the hell kind of a name is Yossarian ?"
>
> Lieutenant Scheisskopf had the facts at his finger tips. "It's Yossarian's name, sir," he explained.

Answer (score 3):

I remember some advertising slogans.

> Everybody doesn't like something.  But nobody doesn't like Sara Lee.

and

> There isn't a car on the road that shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 2):

Another song: [Happy Together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWMXRV28Bzw), by The Turtles

The lines: I can't see me lovin' nobody but you   For all my life.

And: The only one for me is you   And you for me.

(The fact that he says the same thing twice, instead of changing direction, always bugged me.)

Answer (score 2):

From "Maybe This Time" from the musical Cabaret: "Everybody loves a winner/So nobody loved me."  (This exhibits, of course, a very common mistake in quantifier manipulation, which bothers me every time I hear the song.)

Answer (score 2):

Raymond Smullyan gave a nice example in one of his books (I forget now which): Two restaurants have signs on their doors. One says

> "Good food is not cheap."

The other says

> "Cheap food is not good."

The two statements are equivalent, but one makes you think of delicacies, while the other about disgusting greasy bites...

Comment: Funny!  I think the apparent dissonance or paradox between the two interpretations/connotations is resolved (and the humor ruined) by noting that they are just two reflections or facets of one statement of *non*existence:  that there is no food that is cheap and good.  This symmetric version feels more neutral yet says the same thing.

Comment: Incidentally, I also find that a similar statement (namely, that no function is simultaneously entire, bounded, and non-constant) of Liouville's theorem from complex analysis helps prevent [moments such as this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/62749#62749).  Typically it's rendered in the form $(P \wedge Q) \Longrightarrow \neg R$ for whatever reason, whereas $\neg (P \wedge Q \wedge R)$ seems less arbitrary at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

This one might take some extra massaging to make it "mathy" (re: "half" and "part" and "some"), but I like it as a fun twist on Abe Lincoln's classic (which @MattF used in his answer):

> Half of the people can be part right all of the time
>
> Some of the people can be all right part of the time
>
> But all of the people can't be all right all of the time
>
> I think Abraham Lincoln said that

Bob Dylan, in "Talkin' World War III Blues", from *The Freewheelin' Bob Dylan*

Comment: "Some" and "all" are good, but there is no compact way to formalize "half of" with these sorts of quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Phew!... I got first to enter this answer:

The ["Who's on First?" routine](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who's_on_First%3F) by Abbott & Costello.

Answer (score 1):

Can anybody find me somebody to love?

Comment: Those are good quantifiers!  I think the question is whether (exists x)(exists y)(x can find y and I can love y), so it's a pity that the quantifier order is irrelevant.

Comment: The system accused this post as being low-quality. No love from the system.